# a simple phonebook program push back contacts into the vector

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I'm writing a simple phonebook program in c++ not using classes.
I have a function which add a contact. I wonder why it doesn't work! it doesn't push back the contact into the vector I would be very thankful if you could help me. A peace of my code is included.

```
    vector<ContactInfo> add(vector<ContactInfo> contacts, ContactInfo ci){
if(!(isRepetativeContact(contacts, ci)))
    contacts.push_back(ci);
return contacts;
}
```

and here is the "isRepetativeContact" function:

```
    bool isRepetativeContact(const vector<ContactInfo>& contacts, const ContactInfo& ci){
for(int i = 0 ; i < contacts.size() ; i++)
    if((contacts.size() != 0) && (contacts[i] == ci))
        return true;
return false;

}
```

And I overloaded the == operator for ContactInfo struct:

```
    bool operator==(const ContactInfo& ci) const {
    return (firstName == ci.firstName && lastName == ci.lastName &&
     phoneNumber == ci.phoneNumber && emailAddress == ci.emailAddress &&
     id == ci.id );
}
```

Comment: *I wonder why it doesn't work!* - Please describe how it doesn't work.

Comment: What is `ContactInfo` if not a class? Did you implement `operator ==` for it?

Comment: Remove `;` at the end of `if((contacts.size() != 0) && (contacts[i] == ci));`

Comment: @DeanSeo sorry, I meant it doesn't push back the contact into the vector. I edited it.

Comment: @Quentin its a struct and yes I overloaded this operator == for it.

Comment: @DeanSeo thanks but I still have problem for second time that I add a contact

Comment: @shirazy can you show the implementation of your `operator==`?

Comment: @shirazy `struct` declares a class in C++ :)

Comment: @LorenceHernandez I included it

Comment: related:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are recreating an std::set using std::vector. 
Try using an std::set

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );
```

the return value of insert is a pair. The bool indicates whether the value was already in the set or not; (insertion succeeded). The iterator points to the element in the std::set (if the value was already in the set, it points to the existing value)

You cannot have duplicates in a set.